# How to insert the value of a string variable within a string which is part of an list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I insert the value of a string variable within a string which is not going into Python's `print` method but going into a list of strings?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

some_var="/some/path/to/somewhere"
my_list_of_paths = ['A=/a/b/c', 'B=/b/c/d', 'C=some_var']

print(my_list_of_paths)
```

`print(my_list_of_paths)` should print `['A=/a/b/c', 'B=/b/c/d', 'C=/some/path/to/somewhere']` but it prints `['A=/a/b/c', 'B=/b/c/d', 'C=some_var']` which is not the intention here.

Comment: `f'C={some_var}'`, `'C={}'.format(some_var)`

Comment: Ah I need to prepend that with `f`. I was trying 'C={some_var}'. Thanks. It works

Comment: BTW, you have a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) here. An [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) is something different.

Comment: Woops! Yes. I modified the question to call it a list. Thanks

Comment: For the sake of understanding SO rules, why shouldn't there be an answer to this question and only a comment? Is it because the answer is too simple?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer, it's okay to write an answer to this question. But I'm 99% sure that it's duplicate, so it will be closed soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

some_var="/some/path/to/somewhere"
my_list_of_paths = ['A=/a/b/c', 'B=/b/c/d', 'C=' + some_var]

print(my_list_of_paths)
```

The following way of insert the string value with `f` notation also works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

some_var="/some/path/to/somewhere"
my_list_of_paths = ['A=/a/b/c', 'B=/b/c/d', f'C={some_var}']

print(my_list_of_paths)
```